# Checking if string is in uppercase in R

Tags: regex, r, uppercase

Is there simpler method to match regex pattern in its entirety? For example, to check if given string is uppercase the following 2 methods but seem too complex. Checking **stringr** I found no indication for simpler solution either.

**Method 1:**

```
isUpperMethod1 <- function(s) {
  return (all(grepl("[[:upper:]]", strsplit(s, "")[[1]])))
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
isUpperMethod2 <- function(s) {
  m = regexpr("[[:upper:]]+", s)
  return (regmatches(s, m) == s)
}
```

I intentionally omit handling of empty, NA, NULL strings to avoid bloated code.

**The uppercase pattern can be generalized to arbitrarily regex pattern (or character set).**

I see no problems with both solutions above except that they seem excessively complex for the problem solved.

Comment: `s == toupper(s)`?

Comment: I want to keep solution generalizable to more complex pattern.

Comment: When you do get around to think about missing and empty strings, note that `grepl` returns FALSE where the input string is missing.  `str_detect` from `stringr` does the same job as `grepl` but returns `NA` in this case.  Also, you can swap the `+` for a `*` in Matthew's solution to match an empty string.

Comment: @RichieCotton all are great points, thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the `^` and `$` patterns to match the beginning and end of the string

```
grepl("^[[:upper:]]+$", s)
```

Answer (score 20):

Why not just test if the word is identical to itself when converted to upper case with the "toupper" function?

```
word1 <- "TEST"
word1 == toupper(word1)
```

will be `TRUE`

Comment: the question has "generalization" clause discussed in its comments.

Answer (score 11):

If you prefer to live in the `tidyverse`, here's the version using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(s, "^[:upper:]+$")
```